# Exclude products with category id - productCollection

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection

I am currently trying to run a productCollection to try and get a list of products that are not assigned to one or more categories.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$catId = [46]; // category id to exclude
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('cats' => 'catalog_category_product'), 'cats.product_id =         e.entity_id'); // Join with category on product/entity id
$collection->getSelect()->where('cats.category_id', array('nin' => array('finset' => $catId))); // exclude category from collection

echo '<pre>';
echo $collection->getSelect(); // See sql query
print_r($collection->getData());
```

This is what I currently have however it doesn't exclude the fact that these products may be in a child category of the id provided.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

You have to also join the `category_entity` table and then use the `path` field to filter categories.

To do so, it is easier to **left join** categories that **match** your exclude criteria and then filter your collection to only return products with no matches in the joined table.

#### Example code (untested):

```
$excludeId = 46;
$collection->joinTable(
    ['exclude_category_product' => 'catalog/category_product'],
    'product_id=entity_id',
    ['category_id'],
    null,
    'left'
);
$collection->joinTable(
    ['exclude_category' => 'catalog/category'],
    'entity_id=category_id',
    ['entity_id'],
    ['path' => [
        ['like' => '%/'.$excludeId],
        ['like' => '%/'.$excludeId.'/%']
    ]],
    'left'
);
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('exclude_category.entity_id IS NULL'));
```